# I18n in Play Framework 2.4.0

Tags: scala, playframework

Here is my `routes` file:

```
GET /:lang      controller.Application.index(lang: String)
GET /:lang/news controller.Application.news(lang: String)
```

Note that all of them start with `/:lang`.

Currently, I write `Application.scala` as

```
def index(lang: String) = Action {
  implicit val messages: Messages = play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits.applicationMessages(
    Lang(lang), play.api.Play.current)
  Ok(views.html.index("title"))
}
```

In this way, I have to write as many `implicit Messages` as `Action`. Is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Passing just `Lang` is simpler option:

```
def lang(lang: String) = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("play")(Lang(lang)))
}

//template
@(text: String)(implicit lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)
@Messages("hello")
```

You can reuse some code by using action composition, define wrapped request and action:

```
case class LocalizedRequest(val lang: Lang, request: Request[AnyContent]) extends WrappedRequest(request)

def LocalizedAction(lang: String)(f: LocalizedRequest => Result) = {
    Action{ request =>
      f(LocalizedRequest(Lang(lang), request))
    }
}
```

Now you are able to reuse `LocalizedAction` like this:

```
//template
@(text: String)(implicit request: controllers.LocalizedRequest)
@Messages("hello")

//controller
def lang(lang: String) = LocalizedAction(lang){implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index("play"))
}
```

Comment: It seems good, but is it somehow possible to write only `@Messages("hello")` in template?

Comment: Yeah, in both cases you can omit second parenthesis after `@Messages("hello")`, I've edited answer

Comment: The first case works fine. But in the second case, I have to write `@Messages("hello")(request.messages)` or I'll get a compilation error `could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages`. P.S. in play 2.4, the second parameter of `Messages` has been replaced by `play.api.i18n.Messages`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem in the following way.

As @Infinity suggests, I defined wrapped request and action as:

```
case class LocalizedRequest(messages: Messages,
                            request: Request[AnyContent])
  extends WrappedRequest(request)


object Actions {
  def LocalizedAction(lang: String)(f: LocalizedRequest => Result) = {
    Action { request =>
      f(LocalizedRequest(applicationMessages(Lang(lang), current), request))
    }
  }

  object Implicits {
    implicit def localizedRequest2Messages(implicit request: LocalizedRequest): Messages = request.messages
  }
}
```

Now I'm able to use `LocalizedAction` like this:

```
def lang(lang: String) = LocalizedAction(lang) { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index("play"))
}
```

However, in order to omit the `implicit` parameter of `Messages`, which should be a `play.api.i18n.Messages`, I added a line to my template as:

```
@import controllers.Actions.Implicits._
```

Comment: It may be helpful. Instead place `@import controllers.Actions.Implicits._` everywhere, you can set `TwirlKeys.templateImports ++= Seq("controllers.Actions.Implicits._")` in build.sbt.